# Can I use Win32 API ExtractIcon() on dotNet compiled exe?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, icons, registry

I have a program written in C# and I am trying to write a registry script to associate files with my program. In the windows registry there is a "DefaultIcon" location where you can list the executable and iconIndex to use for this association. The problem is this is based on a the ExtractIcon() method in the win32 API and it doesn't seem that I can embed an icon to be used in this way so my icon is used.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\%someName%\DefaultIcon]
@="Path\to\exe,0"
```

Is there any other way to get my icon used in the file type association?

Answer (score 0):

Set the project's icon in its Properties window, and that will work fine.

If you want to embed multiple icons, set a Resource File (also in Project Properties) instead.

Comment: If I embed multiple icons, I cant seem to access them using the indexing in the registry. I want my file icon different than my programs icon, like how excel does it for their files etc.

Comment: That should work.  (although I haven't tried it) At the very least, you could make a separate DLL with the icon.